# free or low cost, cloud based LMS for corporate training programs

Tags: rest, video, cloud, video-conferencing

I am doing researches for finding a good Learning management system for our company to provide corporate training for employees and other users worldwide.

The lms should be a cloud based and it should supports video conferencing.

I am looking for free or low cost cloud based application.

Another option i am looking for is that the lms should provide a REST or communication API to integrate with our system

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You typically won't get video conferencing on an LMS. Some good video conf options (many come with other stuff built in):

- Bluejeans, Microsoft Teams, Hipchat, Slack, Skype, Google Hangouts

Depending on your corporate needs, they will have varying levels of privacy/audit/logging functionality which may be a requirement for you.

You can simply google Learning Management System to get loads of options